# Get second argument in php navigation

Tags: php, navigation, arguments

I am trying to grab the second argument of a URL such as this:

> http://website.com/?p=2?id=ass92jdskdj92

I just want the id portion of the address.  I use the following code to grab the first portion of the address:

```
$p = $_GET[p]; 
$remove = strrchr($p, '?'); 
$p = str_replace($remove, "", $p);
```

Any hints on how to get the second portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments in links are started by `?` and divided by `&`.

That means your link should look like this:

```
http://website.com/?p=2&id=ass92jdskdj92
```

And you get them by:

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: $id = $_GET['id']; still returns a null value

edit: nevermind!  I was leaving in the ? on the id portion.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you fix your link? Notice closely what I did to your link. I changed the latter ``?`` to ``&``

Answer (score 0):

First change the URL

only first argument start with `?` and rest of all is append by `&`

u should try with

```
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Reference:
[parse url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)